# C# delete 2 dynamic controls based only on the first controls clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have some dynamically created `PictureBox`'s and `Label`'s for each `PictureBox`, and a `ContextMenu` with a `ToolStripMenuItem` named "Remove" ... I want to remove only the `PictureBox` and the `Label` that is related to that `PictureBox` that is clicked but this `ContextMenu` is attached to all `PictureBox`'s only, and not to `Label`'s.

Is there a way to delete two controls in one click based only on the first one clicked ?

How to do it ?

Comment: You should really store the PictureBox and Label together as a unit in a **UserControl**.  In lieu of that, though, you can simply store a reference to the associated Label in the PictureBoxes Tag() property when you create them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a reference to the associated Label in the Tag() property of the PictureBox when you create them:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Tag = lbl;
```

Later you can remove them both:

```
// ...assuming "pb" now refers to the PictureBox that fired the ContextMenu...
((Control)pb.Tag).Dispose();
pb.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You  could store the id of another control in the first control as its attribute. Now you could delete the second control using the attribute in the first control click event.

Comment: Could you bring a code example please ? I am a beginner in c# and I really don`t know how to do this ...